# Alamofire 4.9.1 sessionManager.delegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge is not getting assigned in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, client-certificates

The iOS app I'm working on is using Alamofire 4.9.1 and the following code executes without any issues in iOS 14 and below, but not iOS 15.

```
dataProvider.sessionDelegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge = { _, challenge in
                
                print("CHALLENGE ACCEPTED")
                
                if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate {

                    return (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential,
                            cert.urlCredential())
                }

                if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {

                    return (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential,
                            URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!));
                }

                return (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.performDefaultHandling,
                        Optional.none)
            }
```

, where *cert* is a .pfx certificate initialized just before this.

This is preventing the app from accessing information on a server with TLS 1.2 certificate based authentication. In iOS 13 and 14 (supported iOS versions start at 13) the print statement executes, but not in iOS 15 for some reason. In iOS 13 and 14, in Alamofire's SessionDelegate.swift,

```
open func urlSession(
        _ session: URLSession,
        didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)
```

gets called, but in iOS 15 that is replaced by a call to

```
open func urlSession(
        _ session: URLSession,
        task: URLSessionTask,
        didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)
```

Any idea as to what can be causing this and how to address it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by modifying the SessionDelegate.swift file of the Alamofire pod itself. Namely, I initialized the certificate in the SessionDelegate.swift file and passed its urlCredential property to the task delegate's credential property in

```
open func urlSession(
    _ session: URLSession,
    task: URLSessionTask,
    didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)
```

and *voilà*, it worked.

So I re-defined the class (PKCS12) that lets me initialize the certificate inside the SessionDelegate.swift file and the body of the above function now looks like this:

```
if let taskDidReceiveChallenge = taskDidReceiveChallenge {
        let result = taskDidReceiveChallenge(session, task, challenge)
        completionHandler(result.0, result.1)
    } else if let delegate = self[task]?.delegate {
        // this gets executed in iOS 15 and we need to get a credential in order for the delegate to successfully set the disposition required for getting data from the server
        let cert = PKCS12.init(mainBundleResource: "\(certNameHere)",
                               resourceType: "pfx",
                               password: "%^&^%*&")
        delegate.credential = cert.urlCredential()
        delegate.urlSession(
            session,
            task: task,
            didReceive: challenge,
            completionHandler: completionHandler
        )
    } else {
        urlSession(session, didReceive: challenge, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
```

This has solved the issue for us and I hope it is of help to others who may experience similar issues with iOS 15 and Alamofire 4.9.1. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that this may have changed, as the documented behavior hasn't: `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` challenges should be received by the session's delegate, not the task's, unless the session delegate doesn't implement the method at all. I would report this issue to Apple so they can either fix the documentation or the delegate callback itself.

In any event, Alamofire 4 is unsupported and this issue will not be fixed. Please update to Alamofire 5, which rectifies this issue by implementing only the `URLSessionTaskDelegate` version of this method and provides a single hook for this logic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I solved the problem, details below.

Answer (score 0):

I have readed the Alamofire document [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#sessiondelegate).
Something like that:

```swift
let rootQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "org.alamofire.customQueue")
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
queue.underlyingQueue = rootQueue
let delegate = SessionDelegate()
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration,
                         delegate: self,
                         delegateQueue: queue)
let session = Session(session: urlSession, delegate: delegate, rootQueue: rootQueue)
```

and you can trust the server certificate throw URLSessionDelegate.
Don't forget set delegate for it.